# Using a function more directly in a promise

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Is there a way to express this:

```
    imagePFFileFromUrl(exampUrl) // (returns a promise)
    .then(function(xxx))
        // that syntax gives you the results of the
        // imagePFFileFromUrl inside the variable xxx.
        // I then use it in another function which
        // returns another promise...
        {
        return saveImageFile(xxx, anotherArgument) // (returns a promise)
        })
    .then(function(savedPFFile)
```

more like this ..

```
    imagePFFileFromUrl(exampUrl)
    .then(saveImageFile(...the results from imagePFFileFromUrl ...))
    .then(function(savedPFFile)
```

when using promise?

Comment: You are invoking the function rather than passing a function reference with `.then(saveImageFile("name", newImagePFFile))`

Comment: Closer to the root of the issue, those functions need parameters because they have no shared execution context.  If all this were taking place inside an "Avatar" object, for instance, the file url, the PFFile, etc. would be instance data.  You'd then be able to just mention function names as params to `then()` rather than invoke them.

Comment: @danh,  do you mean `.then(saveImageFile)` would work (ie, where it currently says 'pseudocode') .. assuming of course that the arguments were handled elsewise?

Comment: Yes.  The function would be invoked -- sans arguments -- after resolution of the prior promise.  It would get its context (including what would have been params) by virtue of being a member of a class.

Comment: I see.  So, using the `function(blah)` syntax is a way, to get, the results of the previous promise .. in fact in to "blah".  And indeed, using the `function(blah)` syntax is the ONLY way to get those results, there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .then()'s need to have 1 or 2 call back functions. If there is 1, it takes in the resolved value of the promise. If there are two, the second takes the rejected value of the promise. So, no, you can't do what you are trying to do.

---

Here's a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29776055/294884) of the pattern, with two arguments, notice at `return synchUsers`

Comment: This seems to be the situation @Jake, thanks for the consice explanation!

Comment: No problem.

FYI, something I discovered recently, if you have a chain of promises, and try to call response.error or response.success halfway through the chain, it will still continue on executing the rest of the chain, even though you didn't return a promise.  This can cause some unintentional behavior. In the case of calling response.error, it turns out that if you have a promise chain, and you return a rejected promise, it will skip any link in the chain that doesn't have an error handling callback. Hope this saves you a future head ache.

Comment: Hi @JakeT. it's funny you mention that, notice my other question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768731  I'm damned if I can work that out....that sounds like a critical tip though

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to achieve this.  Bind creates a new function with the first parameter being the `this` object and any following parameters being passed to the function.  When calling the new function created by `bind()`, any parameters are in addition to the parameters passed to `bind()`.

```
imagePFFileFromUrl(exampUrl)
  .then(saveImageFile.bind(null, "name"))
  .then(function(savedPFFile)
```

so essentially, you are passing the return values of the first promise as the second parameter to the `saveImageFile` function. With the first parameter being the string value "name".

Comment: bind .. thanks a million .. but I don't understand the "null" there??  did I miss something?

Comment: The first parameter is the functions `this` object.  I set it to null, you can use whatever you want, your saveImageFile probably doesn't use `this` in it's implementation?

Comment: Use null just as I did, you don't need the this object in your saveImageFile.  See the MDN reference on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: ok, I'll look in to it. thanks.   I'm trying to give the results of `imagePFFileFromUrl` to `saveImageFile` (in fact just as I do in the first code example).

Comment: thanks for introducing me to .bind, Preston. I understand how it works now, you can use it to set the "this" value in a function. I simplified the question (so the function has only one parameter).  I fear .bind is not really working here; I tried it extensively and could not get it to work; I don't think `this` relates to getting the resulting promise from the previous call in the chain.  Again thanks for this tip though!

Comment: Since you've changed your question so much my answer no longer applies, but `bind` can do more than setting the `this` object for a function.  It can also set default argument values, which is what I was trying to show you.  You are getting hung up on the first parameter that sets `this` but you should be looking at the second. This would have defaulted the first argument of your saveImageFile function to the string "name" and then the second argument would have been set to the return value of the promise. Thus solving your original problem. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqj35drf/)

Comment: hi Preston - (•) I totally understand what you mean now about just sending null to the first paramater; in the case at hand we don't care about setting `this`, again thanks.  (•) I understand what you're saying: the **second** arg of `bind` would become the first arg of my function; the **third** arg of `bind` would become the return value from the promise, in my function.  Is that just right?  however (•) I just can't get that to work, damnit!  And I see your Fiddle example.  I'm wondering perhaps Parse (cloud code) uses a different implementation of .bind, or some other woe?

Comment: I will continue to experiment with it!  I'm sure you know what you're talking about...